# How to store a dictionary in a Django database model's field

Tags: python, django, dictionary, model, save

I need to save a dictionary in a model's field. How do I do that?

For example I have this code:

```
def create_random_bill(self):
    name_chars = re.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9 -_]")
    bill_name = "".join(random.choice(name_chars for x in range(10)))
    rand_products = random.randint(1,100)
    for x in rand_products:
        bill_products = 
    new_bill = Bill.new(name=bill_name, date=datetime.date, products=bill_products)
    new_bill.save()
```

What do I write for "bill_products=" so it saves some random products, from my Product model to this bill?

This is the bill's model description:

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name="bills")
```

And also the product's model description:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

If there's anything else i should add just leave a comment. Thanks!

Comment: What the heck is a "python database model"?  Are you using a particular ORM or framework? this looks a bit 'django-ish'

Comment: Yes it is Django. I'm just starting to work with it so I might mix up "Python" with "Django". I'll change the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the cleanest thing to do would be to create another "Products" table and have a many-to-many relationship.  (See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships . In the docs they use the example of a pizza having many toppings.)

The other option would be to serialize your bill_products.  In that case, you'd do something like:

```
bill_products = json.dumps([rand_products])
```

This would be outside of the for loop (although, in your example above, rand_products is only a single value, so you'll need to fix that).

Comment: If you could provide an example it would be very nice. I'm afraid I didn't understand how exactly to translate a many-to-many relationship to my code. Am I on the right idea path with saving an array with product names in that field? Or could I do it in a simpler approach?

Comment: @reos You are on on the right track.  Here is a full example: https://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0_91/models/many_to_many/

Answer (score 21):

I just discovered the [django-jsonfield](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield) package, which

> is a reusable Django field that allows you to store validated JSON in your model.

Looks like a viable option to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's good to know, even if this issue has been fixed a long time ago.

Comment: This repo is not maintained since 2017. https://github.com/adamchainz/django-jsonfield is a fork of 2nd solution.

Also, PostGres supports JSON fields natively: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

Answer (score 10):

One convenient way to store a JSON representation in a model is to use a custom field type:

```
class JSONField(models.TextField):
    """
    JSONField is a generic textfield that neatly serializes/unserializes
    JSON objects seamlessly.
    Django snippet #1478

    example:
        class Page(models.Model):
            data = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)


        page = Page.objects.get(pk=5)
        page.data = {'title': 'test', 'type': 3}
        page.save()
    """

    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value == "":
            return None

        try:
            if isinstance(value, basestring):
                return json.loads(value)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        return value

    def get_db_prep_save(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        if value == "":
            return None
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            value = json.dumps(value, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
        return super(JSONField, self).get_db_prep_save(value, *args, **kwargs)
```

I saved this utils/fields.py and in my model `from utils.fields import JSONField`. There are many more goodies in the [django-annoying](https://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying) app, which is where this snippet came from.

Answer (score 10):

Using a custom field type is my preferred solution - I'd rather have a few lines of custom code than support an entire 3rd party library for a single field type.  Tony Abou-Assaleh has a great solution, but won't work for newer versions of Django.

This is verified to work with Django 1.10.4

```
import json

from django.db import models
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder


class JSONField(models.TextField):
    """
    JSONField is a generic textfield that neatly serializes/unserializes
    JSON objects seamlessly.
    Django snippet #1478

    example:
        class Page(models.Model):
            data = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)


        page = Page.objects.get(pk=5)
        page.data = {'title': 'test', 'type': 3}
        page.save()
    """

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value == "":
            return None

        try:
            if isinstance(value, str):
                return json.loads(value)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        return value

    def from_db_value(self, value, *args):
        return self.to_python(value)

    def get_db_prep_save(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        if value == "":
            return None
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            value = json.dumps(value, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
        return value
```

Comment: This does not handle serialization (`manage.py dumpdata`), does not handle lookups in db, does not handle editing in Django adming (because representation shown is that of serialized dict), etc. Maybe in the end using a 3rd party lib saves you from running into errors.

Answer (score 4):

If postgres is your backend, consider the hstore field which has native support from django

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this has long been answered and resolved. And the backend for this was SQLLite

Answer (score 3):

I think that I would create the field as models.CharField() and then encode the dictionary as a JSON string and save that string into the database. Then you can decode the JSON string back into a dictionary when you read it out.

Comment: I added the Bill's model description.

Answer (score 3):

You can use serialization/deserialization from pickle module:

http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 1):

If using PostGres you can store it in natively supported JSON field:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

Otherwise I'd recommend @ramiro answer with 3rd party lib https://stackoverflow.com/a/16437627/803174

Answer (score 1):

according to Django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) you can use :

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models

class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data = JSONField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and create with this :

```
Dog.objects.create(name='Rufus', data={
     'breed': 'labrador',
     'owner': {
         'name': 'Bob',
         'other_pets': [{
             'name': 'Fishy',
         }],
     },
})
```

I hope this can assist you.