# Adding json to new Django database

Tags: python, json, django

I'm trying to create a database in Django with data stored in json.

```
 {
   'Vincent van Gogh': 
       {'The Starry Night': ['starryLink'], 
        'Irises': ['irisesLink']}, 
   'Leonardo da Vinci': 
       {'Mona Lisa': ['monalisalink'], 
        'The Last Supper': ['lastsupperlink']},
 }
```

Do I need to rewrite the above json into the format below?

```
[
{
    "model": "model.artistModel",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "artist": "Vincent van Gogh",
        "title": "The Starry Night",
        "link": ["link.com"]
    }
},
```

I saw some examples of creating a Django db from a json but none looked like my json file. Do I have to script my data into a db with loops and such or can Django do it automatically?

Comment: Are you talking about Django or Django Rest Framework?

Comment: Just the basic Django app. I haven't learned what Django Rest is yet. I'm just trying to create a new Django database with data stored in json

Comment: this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686409/how-to-store-a-dictionary-in-a-django-database-models-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I had to rewrite my json file to be compliant with the Django model. I created my model in models.py to look like

```
class Art(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    artist = models.CharField()
    link = models.URLField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s, %s' % (self.title, self.artist, self.link)
```

I went to the /admin/ panel, clicked on the Art model, and put in data and saved it. Then I ran

`python manage.py dumpdata mydata.json`

to see what the database would put out. The json it put out was in this format

```
[
{
     "pk": 1,  
     "model": "model.artistModel",
     "fields": {
         "artist": "Vincent van Gogh",
         "title": "The Starry Night",
         "link": "link.com"
     }
},
```

So I rearranged my json file to have that same structure, dropped in in my django /fixtures folder then ran

```
python manage.py loaddata myfixture.json
```

and like magic Django populated the database with all my data.

Answer (score 1):

There is package [Django Json Field](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield). It has support of Python 3 and Django 1.7.
Example:

```
from django.db import models
from jsonfield import JSONField

class MyModel(models.Model):
  json = JSONField()
```

Comment: I don't need to keep my json file intact. I just want to take the data and make a mysql database out of it for queries.

Comment: @edmund_spenser Are you talkink about json file like some initial data from which you will ceate a DB? Without created models in app?

Comment: That's right, I don't even need the models really. I want to set up a database and then use it with Django.

Comment: I think you will still need to create models fro data that you want to loadinto db. For example model - Painter for your data from example. And then use initial.json like in this tutorial - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/initial-data/