# How to implement dictionary-like field in Django model?

Tags: django, dictionary, model

The problem: a group of several people can use instruments of different types, but the instruments of the same type are not distinguishable. For instance, a group could use 3 hammers and 4 axes, but we don't need to distinguish individual axes or hammers. 
*UPD:* One day we could use another instrument type we can't think of now.

How to design a Django model in this case?

My thoughts:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Group(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    members = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    equip = ???
```

I've found [this question on StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686409/how-to-store-a-dictionary-in-a-django-database-models-field) and a [code snippet for a Django Dictionary model](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2451/), but I am still not sure what approach to choose. 
Even more, there are **django-jsonfield** and **django-picklefield** suitable for dictionaries.

Also, do I really need a dictionary here?

Comment: first of all you need to decide whether this is the right approach. normalizing your database is probably a better idea

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your comment. If I do distinguish individual axes, I can normalize the DB. But I don't, and when I ask someone to fill in a report, he reports "we used 2 axes and 3 hammers", and this is exactly the info I want to store.  //  Another approach that I see is to make our set of available instrument types constant. But one day we could use another tool we can't think of now.

Comment: So what you really need is a table that goes like `tool|job|number_used`

Comment: Thanks! I will ponder over that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have persons, that are related to groups. You assign group of persons to specific Job and track equipment by job, equipment type and its count.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)

class Job(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)

class EquipmentUsage(models.Model)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
    equip_name = models.CharField()
    count = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer as well as comments from e4c5 have solved my problem.