# Database model custom JSONField values persisting between test cases

Tags: json, django, django-database, django-nose

I'm using a Django database model to store objects corresponding to a remote ticket service. In testing this model, I'm running several tests to make sure that log messages work correctly for the database model - I'm using Django-nose to run these tests.

The database model looks something like this, using the `JSONField` from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41839021/2648811) with a small modification to support lists as well as dicts:

```
class TicketEntity(django.db.models.Model)
    tickets = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default=[], serialize=True)
    queued_ticket_data = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default=[], serialize=True)
    ...
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def queue_output_for_ticket(self, log_data):
        self.queued_ticket_data += [log_data]
        self.save()

    def push_ticket(self):
        self.tickets += [self.queued_ticket_data]
        self.queued_ticket_data = []
        self.save()
        return True
```

The tests (in the order they appear to get run) look like this:

```
def test_ticket_entity_push_ticket(self):
    entity = TicketEntity.create()
    entity.queue_output_for_ticket("log output")
    entity.queue_output_for_ticket("more log output")
    entity.push_ticket()
    self.assertEquals(entity.tickets, [[log_data, log_data_1]])
    self.assertFalse(entity.queued_ticket_data)

 def test_ticket_entity_queue_output_for_ticket(self):
    entity = TicketEntity.create()
    log_data = "Here's some output to log.\nHere's another line of output.\nAnd another."
    entity.queue_output_for_ticket(log_data)
    self.assertEquals(entity.queued_ticket_data, [log_data])
```

The first test passes, perfectly fine. The second test fails on that assert statement, because the `entity.queued_ticket_data` looks like this:

```
["log output", 
 "more log output",
 "Here's some output to log.\nHere's another line of output.\nAnd another."]
```

Those first two elements are there at the very start of the test, immediately after we call `TicketEntity.create()`. They shouldn't be there - the new instance should be clean because we're creating it from scratch.

Similarly, `tickets` is pre-filled as well. The `TicketEntity` has other fields that are not `JSONField`s, and they do not seem to exhibit this problem.

Can someone shed some light on why this problem might be happening, and what kind of modification we'd need for a fix?

Comment: This is a variant of the [mutable default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) gotcha, and is specifically mentioned in [the docs for JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField).

Comment: That seems to have been the problem, thanks! We didn't know that JSONField was already a thing, so we never thought to look in the documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)