# How to save a list of dictionaries as each object in a Django database model's field?

Tags: python, django

I will make the question I asked ([How to store a dictionary in a Django database model's field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68248414/how-to-store-a-dictionary-in-a-django-database-models-field/68248750?noredirect=1#comment120647150_68248750)) better understood:

I got this dictionary

```
sample_dict =  [

{'sale_id': 14,
  'name': 'Macarena',
  'fecha': datetime.date(2021, 3, 11),
  'debe': 500.0},
 {'sale_id': 14,
  'name': 'Macarena',
  'fecha': datetime.date(2021, 4, 11),
  'debe': 500.0},
 {'sale_id': 15,
  'name': 'Yamila',
  'fecha': datetime.date(2021, 4, 14),
  'debe': 2000.0}

]
```

And I would like to store it in the Django DataBase (SQLite3) like this:

[image]

BUT before append this dict to the DB I would like to clear the Database and avoid duplicated values (or remove duplicates after append the dict to the db)

If I choose remove duplicates, I should remove duplicates from the "sale_id", "name", "fecha" and "debe" columns, not only from "sale_id" because I got many "sale_id" with the same number but with different dates ("fecha").

I've tried this but every time I run the "objects.create" I got duplicated values in the DB:

```
class Creditos1(models.Model):

    sale_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    debe = models.IntegerField(default=0)

for i in range(0,len(h)):
    Creditos1.objects.create(name=h[i]['name'], sale_id=h[i]['sale_id'], fecha=h[i]['fecha'], debe=h[i]['debe'])
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everytime you run your code, new objects will be created, regardless if they are in the DB already or not. You do not provide a unique ID.

To remove ALL objects you can simply run

```
Creditos1.objects.all().delete()
```

to check if data is already in the Database to avoid adding it multiple times, you  can for example use a shortcut

```
credit, created = Creditos1.objects.get_or_create(name=..., sale_id=...)
```

#### Edit: Some Tricks (offtopic)

Btw. if you loop over a list in python there is a shorter way to do so:

```
for item in h:
    Creditos1.objects.create(name=item['name'], sale_id=item['sale_id'] ...)
```

and if the keys are exactly the same as the arguments you want to pass, you can automatically unpack them using

```
for item in h:
    Creditos1.objects.create(**item)
```

#### Putting all together:

after running the delete command or (re)moving the sqlite file, this should avoid storing the same data multiple times.

```py
# models.py

class Creditos1(models.Model):
    sale_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    debe = models.IntegerField(default=0)


# view or script

sample_dict =  [
{'sale_id': 14,
  'name': 'Macarena',
  'fecha': datetime.date(2021, 3, 11),
  'debe': 500.0},
 {'sale_id': 14,
  'name': 'Macarena',
  'fecha': datetime.date(2021, 4, 11),
  'debe': 500.0},
 {'sale_id': 15,
  'name': 'Yamila',
  'fecha': datetime.date(2021, 4, 14),
  'debe': 2000.0}
]


for item in sample_dict:
    c, new = Creditos1.objects.get_or_create(**item)
    # optional:
    if not new:
        print("Entry already in the DB:")
        print(c)
```